# Keep installer size down by reusing files / components

Tags: installshield

Let's say I have 2 features, both use abc.dll, and both reference it from their respective current directories.

So the output will look like this :

- Feature1

  ```
  abc.dll
  ```
- Feature2

  ```
  abc.dll
  ```

I've created 2 components for this. In reality I have many features and many dll's that are shared, and my installer size is nearly 1GB.

What I am looking for is a smarter way to do this, using IS 2015 professional.

What I've looked at so far:

1. Merge modules: Not sure if this would work, also it means I need to maintain the merge modules manually should files be upgraded.
2. DuplicateFile, via direct editor, but this wouldn't work because there is no way to have this bound to a feature, only a component.
3. A hidden feature which would install the shared files to the target system, then a post script which would copy these files to their respective features, and delete the folder of this feature.

Is there a best practice method to implement what I need?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you installing the same file into two different locations? also, can any of the features be enabled/disabled by the user?

Comment: Yeah same files to different locations, and features can be enabled / disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The most suitable approach in this case is, indeed, merge modules. I am not sure why the concern about maintaining them - you should have an automated build process that creates all merge modules and then builds your main installer with the newly created modules.
However, in my opinion, merge modules are a bit cumbersome to use if you have a lot of custom actions.

An alternative to merge modules - assuming you are using a Windows Installer project - is using small MSI packages which you "chain" to your main installer (you can chain multiple packages with different conditions and supply different properties). Here too, you should have a build process which builds all those small msi packages and then builds the main installer.

If you don't want to have this kind of 'sub-projects', then the option of a hidden feature with a post action is acceptable, I've seen it, and done it, a few times. Note that if you target Windows 7 or later, instead of physically copying the files and deleting them, you can use symbolic links (using the `mklink` command), which helps reduce the installation's foot print on the target system (and make patching easier - you replace the original file, and all its links are updated automatically).

Comment: Merge modules won't work, because they also have a 1:1 relationship between module and output directory.

Comment: Also chained msi's won't work either, because each sub msi gets the files, and again duplication.